# c# rectangle intersect wrong result point

Tags: c#, intersection, rectangles

i have 2 rectangles, i want to know left top point of intersect + width & height

```
//image
Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(121, 74, 614, 240);

//crop area
Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(40, -40, 240, 240);

Rectangle rectangle3 = new Rectangle();

if (rectangle1.IntersectsWith(rectangle2))
{
    rectangle3 = Rectangle.Intersect(rectangle2, rectangle1);
}
```

and in rectangle3 i have result {X = 121 Y = 74 Width = 159 Height = 126}

how?? why?? top left point is wrong, but width & height is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried drawing those? I think the answer is right.

Comment: Yes, the answer is right. OP needs some graph paper and a pencil. ;)